# Star rating by Rogie

Tags: javascript, html, css

I decided to use those very nice rating stars which I found on this page:
http://rog.ie/blog/css-star-rater

html

```
<span class="star-rating">
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5"><i></i>
</span>
```

css

```
.star-rating {
    font-size: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background:  url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAgMjAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIwIDIwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjREREREREIiBwb2ludHM9IjEwLDAgMTMuMDksNi41ODMgMjAsNy42MzkgMTUsMTIuNzY0IDE2LjE4LDIwIDEwLDE2LjU4MyAzLjgyLDIwIDUsMTIuNzY0IDAsNy42MzkgNi45MSw2LjU4MyAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
background-size: contain;}

.star-rating i {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    z-index: 1;
    background:  url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAgMjAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIwIDIwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjRkZERjg4IiBwb2ludHM9IjEwLDAgMTMuMDksNi41ODMgMjAsNy42MzkgMTUsMTIuNzY0IDE2LjE4LDIwIDEwLDE2LjU4MyAzLjgyLDIwIDUsMTIuNzY0IDAsNy42MzkgNi45MSw2LjU4MyAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
background-size: contain;}

.star-rating input {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    opacity: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}

.star-rating input:hover + i,
.star-rating input:checked + i {
    opacity: 1;
}
.star-rating i ~ i {
    width: 40%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i {
    width: 60%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i ~ i {
    width: 80%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i {
    width: 100%;
}

.choice {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    display: block;
}
```

Author uses JS to run it but I would like to use it without JS. My idea was to put it into a form but a problem is that it always sends a value of 1. Does anyone know how I could remake it so it would actually work like a proper input form? I do believe that the problem is CSS which prevents from choosing another value than 1. Thank you for any feedback.

Comment: You said you put it into a form and it always sends a value of 1; could you show this code?

Comment: Here is an example that works: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/xR7Cy/ The error have to be in the value getting method.

Comment: Well I wanted to let it work without JS. Purely html.